# Set select list value via PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am calling an apex page via URL and pass all item values in the request like

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:44:&SESSION.:INSERT:&DEBUG.:44:P44_NAME,P44_DESCRIPTION,P44_PARENT_PK_ID:#NAME#,#DESCRIPTION#,#PARENT_PK_ID#_#PK_ID#
```

In my case I have to check if the row has a parent key reference value. If yes I have to set the parent key reference value to `P44_PARENT_PK_ID`. Otherwise, I have to set the key reference value (`#PK_ID#`) to `P44_PARENT_PK_ID`. That's why I am passing both values split with "_" in the URL.

On page 44 I have a process on the "Before Regions" process point:

```
DECLARE 
  v_demilitedstring varchar2(100);
BEGIN
   v_demilitedstring := v('P44_PARENT_PK_ID');

   IF nvl(to_number(substr(v_demilitedstring, 1, instr(v_demilitedstring, '_', 1, 1) -1)), 0) = 0 then
        :P44_PARENT_PK_ID := substr(v_demilitedstring, instr(v_demilitedstring, '_', -1, 1) +1);
   ELSE
        :P44_PARENT_PK_ID := substr(v_demilitedstring, 1, instr(v_demilitedstring, '_', 1, 1) -1);
   end if;
END;
```

I set the success message as `&P44_PARENT_PK_ID.` to check if the right value is assigned to it. The procedure is working fine and the correct value is set to `P44_PARENT_PK_ID`. However, the assigned value is not selected in select list (Meaning the display name of value is not displayed).

How can I trigger the select list item to change it's display value?

Comment: Are you trying to change the options in the select list or the value that is selected?

Comment: I'd look at the Source type for the item, as well as double-check that the LOV for the select list includes the id (or you could temporarily change it to a Text Field to check).

Comment: @eaolson: I am trying to change the value. The value is set, but the display name is not selected in UI.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Yes. I checked this already. The select list LOV includes the ID that I am assigning via PLSQL code. That's why I wonder why it is not displaying the set value's display name.

Comment: What is the setup for the item? Is the select list's source set to "Always", "Database Column", "PARENT_PK_ID" ? What is the PK for the fetch row process - PK_ID?

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you have a select list generating correctly and you you want to change the value that is selected when the page loads. For that, go to the `Source` section of the select list item. You can drive that based on another page item, like P44_PARENT_PK_ID, a query, or a number of other options.

Make sure that the list of values for your select list will have the source value in it.